# defining 2 constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to define 2 constants in Ruby such that the second one depends of the first one. Here is what I'm doing:

```
class MyClass

  MY_CONST = [
    :aaa,
    :bbb,
    :ccc
  ]

  MY_CONST2 = self::MY_CONST << :ddd
end
```

However, the code below prints the value of the second constant for some reason.

```
puts MyClass::MY_CONST
puts '------------------'
puts MyClass::MY_CONST2


##################
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
------------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Why? Is there any way to get rid of it except defining them as `def`?

```
def self.my_const
  [:aaa, :bbb, :ccc]
end

def self.my_const2
  self::my_const << :ddd
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` operator appends to the array on its left. So when you append `:ddd` you are appending it to `MY_CONST`.

One way to avoid this is to use `.dup` to make a copy of the array before appending:

```
class MyClass

    MY_CONST = [
        :aaa,
        :bbb,
        :ccc
    ]

    MY_CONST2 = MY_CONST.dup << :ddd
end
```

(Thanks to @ShawnBalestracci for pointing out the problem with the `.clone` code I used at first.)

Or use the `+` operator as @DavidGrayson suggested, which makes a new array instead of modifying the original arrays:

```
class MyClass

    MY_CONST = [
        :aaa,
        :bbb,
        :ccc
    ]

    MY_CONST2 = MY_CONST + [ :ddd ]
end
```

Either way prints what you were looking for:

```
puts MyClass::MY_CONST
puts '------------------'
puts MyClass::MY_CONST2

aaa
bbb
ccc
------------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Comment: It's easier to just do `MY_CONST + [:ddd]`

Comment: If MY_CONST is frozen, then `MY_CONST.clone << :ddd` will raise an exception.   I would suggest using `.dup` instead of `.clone`

Comment: why does it require to use + and [:ddd], but .dup << and :ddd (as a symbol, not an array)?

Comment: @MariusKavansky - Try it and find out. Run `irb` and type in these two examples: First, `[:a] + :b`, and second, `[:a] << [:b]`. What is the result of each one?

Answer (score 4):

You're accessing the constant wrong. It's a class constant, so, while you're defining that class you can reference it locally:

```
class MyClass

  MY_CONST = [
    :aaa,
    :bbb,
    :ccc
  ]

  MY_CONST2 = MY_CONST + [:ddd]
end
```

Plus, you're mutating `MY_CONST`, which isn't what you want to do. `<<` changes the value of `MY_CONST` then assigns to `MY_CONST2` so they're both the same:

```
MyClass::MY_CONST.object_id
# => 70359163729880
MyClass::MY_CONST2.object_id
# => 70359163729880
```

After defining `MY_CONST2` correctly:

```
[14] (pry) main: 0> MyClass::MY_CONST
[
    [0] :aaa,
    [1] :bbb,
    [2] :ccc
]
[15] (pry) main: 0> MyClass::MY_CONST2
[
    [0] :aaa,
    [1] :bbb,
    [2] :ccc,
    [3] :ddd
]
```

Comment: and what's the difference between your code and mine? what's the value of MY_CONST?

Comment: @AlanDert because `+` returns a new object while `>>` modifies the existing one.

Comment: @JanDvorak, it's not `>>`, it's `<<`.

Comment: @theTinMan ah, right.  Sorry for the `>>`. As for "won't work at all", then how do you explain that "the [asker's] code prints the value of the second constant for some reason"?

Comment: @AlanDert, `why does +[:ddd] work`? Because that's the difference between the `+` operator and `<<`. You need to look at [`Array.+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) and [`Array.<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) in the documentation.

Comment: @JanDvorak, because the constant `self::MY_CONST1` isn't defined at all in the OP's example code. It has to be defined someplace. `self::MY_CONST` was defined, but not with a `1` appended.

Comment: @theTinMan if `self::MY_CONST` isn't defined anywhere, then why `MY_CONST2 = self::MY_CONST << :ddd` doesn't crash? No doubts `MY_CONST1` isn't ;-)

Comment: `self::MY_CONST` is defined. It's also unnecessary to specify it using `self::` as the constant is in scope inside the class during the definition phase. Removing `self::` is cleaner and clearer. `<<` can't be used because it mutates either `self::MY_CONST` and `MY_CONST`, since they're the same, and, after the mutation, assigns the result to `MY_CONST2`.